# PHP Sort three alpha characters in custom order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort groups of three characters like LMH, MMH, HHL etc all containing only the characters L, M and H but I need them sorted in the order LMH. This is what I have but not sure how to compare them. The $val array doesn't work when there are duplicate characters. It's a string that is broken into an array by the function.

```
function sortit($str) {
 $val = ['L' => 0, 'M' => 1, 'H' => 2];
 $parts = str_split($str);
 foreach ($parts as $value) {
   $order[$val[$value]] = $value;
 }
 ksort($order);
 return implode('',$parts);
 }
```

Input:

```
MLH 
HLL 
MHM 
LHM 
MLH 
LHM 
MHL
```

Desired output:

```
LMH 
LLH 
MMH 
LMH 
LMH 
LMH 
LMH
```

Comment: Consider this: what's that `$val` array doing? You aren't using it at all.

Comment: Yes I mentioned that, I tried using it but it didn't work with duplicates like MMH.

Comment: So why is it still there? Clean up your code first.

Comment: Because I don't know how to do it but if I don't post what I've tried then people complain that I didn't post any code. The code is there but the comparison code with the $val array doesn't work so I removed it but the array is still there since there may still be a way to use it.

Comment: So you tried _something_ with `$val` (but we don't know what), and now it remains there as dead code (that we don't know how you intended to use). Clean this up; post several snippets if you have to. You might even solve the problem yourself this way — there's a reason why we insist so much on MCVEs.

Comment: Define compare function using `$val` as `return $val[$a] - $val[$b];` (using `usort`)

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 Added what I tried but I didn't see the point since it didn't work and I find normally the answers are normally nothing like what I tried.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 Lol the answers used my $val array idea but the actual code was indeed completely different to what I tried. Oh well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `usort` [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function sortit($str) {
   $val = ['L' => 0, 'M' => 1, 'H' => 2];
   $parts = str_split($str);
   usort($parts, function ($a, $b) use ($val) {return $val[$a] - $val[$b];});
   return implode("", $parts);
 }
```

Use it as:

```
echo sortit("MLH"); // output LMH
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$val = ['L' => 0, 'M' => 1, 'H' => 2];
$strings = ['HML', 'MHM', 'LHL'];

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    $arr = str_split($str);
    usort($arr, function($val1, $val2) use ($val) {
        return $val[$val1] <=> $val[$val2];
    });
    var_dump(implode('', $arr));
}
```

You can sort it with usort and a custom compare function. Here I used your val array, which was a good first idea.

Comment: This answer is great too.